# In telegram Bot, / doesn't pop up /caps as coded

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am new to telegram bot. I have a quick question, I followed the telegram bot documentation and here is my code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler,MessageHandler, Filters
import logging

updater = Updater(token='<Enter Token>')

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(bot, update):
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")


def caps(bot, update, args):
    text_caps = ' '.join(args).upper()
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=text_caps)


start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

caps_handler = CommandHandler('caps', caps, pass_args=True)
dispatcher.add_handler(caps_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

Now when I go and execute my script.

If I type /caps hi, it returns HI as expected.

But I thought when I will type / it will give me option like /cap in pop up. But it doesn't

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe currently there is no API to register /-command autocompletion, and you have to manually list all the commands you plan to implement with BotFather, via `/setcommands`.

At least the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands) suggests so.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)